# How to put a default image in a img

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I want to do is make a default image to the img tag if the user has not choose a profile picture on his account.

current output:http://jsfiddle.net/LvsYc/2973/

http://s38.photobucket.com/user/eloginko/media/profile_male_large_zpseedb2954.jpg.html

script:

```
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

$("#imgInp").change(function(){
    readURL(this);
});
```

Comment: Just use CSS to give the div a background image. Then any real image will cover it.

Comment: @j08691 there's that broken image that shows on some browsers to deal with then.

Comment: In that case, you could hide it with `img[src="#"] { display: none; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a quick little script to somewhat handle this:

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LvsYc/3102/

```
$(function () {
    var loader = 'http://i38.photobucket.com/albums/e149/eloginko/profile_male_large_zpseedb2954.jpg';
    $('img[data-src]:not([src])').each(function () {
        var $img = $(this).attr('src', loader),
            src  = $img.data('src'),
            $clone = $img.clone().attr('src', src);
        $clone.on('load', function () {
            $img.attr('src', src);
        });
    });
});
```

Basically, here's what happens:

1. On load, iterate through all image tags that have a `data-src` but no `src` set.
2. Clone the `img` tag and set its `src` to the `data-src`.
3. Once the cloned `img` has loaded, set the original `img` tag's `src` to the `data-src`.

There are tons of ways to handle this scenario, and I'm sure there are better ones out there than this, but this should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/LvsYc/3103/) a fiddle showing what was mentioned in the comments:

**HTML**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <input type='file' id="imgInp" />
    <div class="img">
        <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" />
    </div>
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
img {
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
}
img[src="#"] {
    display: none;
}
.img {
    background: url('http://i38.photobucket.com/albums/e149/eloginko/profile_male_large_zpseedb2954.jpg');
    background-position: -20px -10px;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

The javascript is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Handle the onError event for the image to reassign its source using JavaScript:

```
function imgError(image) {
    image.onerror = "";
    image.src = "/images/noimage.gif";
    return true;
}

<img src="image.png" onerror="imgError(this);"/>
```

Or without a JavaScript function:

```
<img src="image.png" onError="this.onerror=null;this.src='/images/noimage.gif';" />
```